# Selector to click on div loaded with AJAX - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I am trying to create an event that, on click of the div-wrapper, gets a data-value from the tag. To bind events on elements that on document.ready do not exist, I have to use the "on-selector" right?

On document ready my HTML is:

```
<div class="dashboard_container">
  <div class="ab-builder-el el-empty ui-droppable" ordering="-0.5">
    <p>Plaats hier je element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

On drag/drop I add a part of HTML below the div mentioned above (with class el-empty) using jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 //Initialize variables
    var generatedID = 1;
    var elementName = null;
    //Initialize droppable elements
    dropInit();
    //Draggable 
    $('.ab-nav-element').draggable({
            appendTo: '.scroll-container',
            revert: 'invalid',
            cursor: "move", 
            distance: 50,
            revertDuration: 250,
            helper: 'clone',
            start: function(){
                $('.el-empty').addClass('el-receptive');
                elementName = $(this).data('original-title');
                // console.log("draggable start, elementName: "+elementName);
            },
            stop: function(){
                $('.el-receptive').removeClass('el-receptive');
                elementName = null;
            }
        });



    //Function droppable
    function dropInit () {
        // console.log("droppable start, elementName: "+elementName);
        $('.ab-builder-el').droppable({
        hoverClass : 'ui-hover',
        drop: function() {
            var dropContent = '<div id="'+elementName+'-'+generatedID+'" ordering="0" class="ab-builder-el panel" data-element="'+elementName+'"></div><div class="ab-builder-el el-empty" ordering="0.5"><p>Plaats hier je element</p></div>';
            $(this).after(dropContent);
            var divID = '#'+ $(this).next('.panel').attr('id');
            generatedID++;
            $(divID).load("builder-loader.php",{
                elementName: elementName,
                divID:divID 
            });
            dropInit();
        }
    })};
});
```

The AJAX call changes the HTML to this:

```
<div class="dashboard_container">
  <div class="ab-builder-el el-empty ui-droppable" ordering="-0.5">
    <p>Plaats hier je element</p>
  </div>
  <div id="element_text_columns-1" ordering="0" class="ab-builder-el panel ui-droppable" data-element="element_text_columns"><div class="row" background-color:default_background_color;"="">
  <div class="ab-builder-el el-empty ui-droppable" ordering="0.5">
    <p>Plaats hier je element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I then like to do is to select my div with ID: "element_text_columns-1"" and read out the data-element value.

I tried using LOTS of selectors, but none of them seem to work? I have the following:

```
$('.dashboard_container').children('.panel').on("click", function(){
    console.log('children');
    var clickedElement = $(this).data('element');
    if(typeof clickedElement != 'undefined'){console.log(clickedElement);}
});
```

But this does not seem to work at all.
Any way to target the div ?

Comment: Try once with `$('.dashboard_container').on("click", '.panel', function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use click event `on()` because the tag you want to select is generated dynamicly with js (like **Satpal** mentioned in comment) and then simple selector like `$(this).data( "element")`.

```js
$('.dashboard_container').on("click", '.panel', function(){
    alert($(this).data( "element"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard_container">
  <div class="ab-builder-el el-empty ui-droppable" ordering="-0.5">
    <p>Plaats hier je element</p>
  </div>
  <div id="element_text_columns-1" ordering="0" class="ab-builder-el panel ui-droppable" data-element="element_text_columns"><div class="row" background-color:default_background_color;"="">
  <div class="ab-builder-el el-empty ui-droppable" ordering="0.5">
    <p>Plaats hier je element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE :** You have a malformed tag in the HTML generated by ajax :

```
<div class="row" background-color:default_background_color;"="">
```

You have to fix it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Allthough using `on()` you have to rebind events on dynamically created DOM elements. Lets say you have a container `<div id="foo"></div>`.

### $(element).on('click', fn) does not affect dynamically created elements

This will alert 'bar', because it is bind after the element is added. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqeLL47p/1/))

```
var panel = $('<div class="panel">foo</div>');
$('#foo').append(panel);

$('.panel').on('click', function(){
    alert('bar');
});
```

This will not alert anything, because you bind the event and afterwards the element is added. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqeLL47p/))

```
$('.panel').on('click', function(){
    alert('bar');
});

var panel = $('<div class="panel">foo</div>');
$('#foo').append(panel);
```

### $(document).on('click', element, fn) affects dynamically created elements

So you have to rebind your events every single time you add a new element. If performance does not matter that much, you could use another syntax so you do not need to rebind them. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqeLL47p/2/))

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel', function(){
    alert('bar');
});

var panel = $('<div class="panel">foo</div>');
$('#foo').append(panel);
```

### Easiest Fix for your Problem

```
$(document).on('click', '.dashboard_container .panel', function(){
    var clickedElement = $(this).data('element');
    if(typeof clickedElement != 'undefined'){console.log(clickedElement);}
});
```

**Note**: document can be replaced with just a parent div. This works because the click event is bind on a existing parent div and the selector given is checked every time you click the element. that's also why it is worse performance wise.

Comment: Thank you for you very clear explanation on how it works. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You said that:

> on click of the **div-wrapper**, gets a data-value from the tag

So, I think what you want is to assign the `click` event to the wrapper, then, get value of its descendants. To do that, we use this:

```
        $('.dashboard_container').click(function(){
            var data = $(this).find('.panel').data('element');
            alert(data);
        });
```

To prove that the code above works with dynamic HTML, I'm posting my tested code here.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(function(){
        $('#foo').click(function(){
            var className = $(this).find('.panel').data('element');
            alert(className);
        });

        var panel = $('<div class="panel" data-element="test">foo</div>');
        $('#foo').append(panel);
    });
```

**Result**: I get the `data-element` alerted (test) when I click the div.

Comment: That will not work because the element `dashboard_container` is dynamiclly added with JS code.

Comment: That because the HTML you test on is not generated by JS.

Comment: Look at my edited part. It seems that `.find()` can work with dynamic HTML :)

Comment: This works too, thank you :D @ Zakaria: maybe it is unclear in my OP  but the dashboard-container is not dynamically added.